# Best way to draw winning line in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: css, html

I'm making Tic Tac Toe game using HTML, CSS and Javascript. For the 9 boxes I've used a table which is horizontally centred. I wish to draw a straight line across the winning combination. Should I use svg, canvas, div or anything else? 
[image]

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>


... 

</table>
```

Comment: please add whatever code you have to the question.

Comment: it can be a background image , from an: image, gradien, svg or whatever you already used to draw the rest :)

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose 3 (2 invinsible 1 visible svg) lines

```html
<svg height="210" width="500">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
```